# Need help on imported GLTF model with changing texture of it

Tags: three.js, textures, gltf

I am implementing 3d model with Three.js on my web application. The problem is that updating texture image on imported gltf model is not working correctly. I first exported the model from 3ds max using gltf-export plug-in. And i get 3 files which are .bin, .gltf, .texture image file. After that, I put those three files and other texture image files in the same folder.

After that, I loaded gltf file on my web using GLTFLoader from Three.js. It worked fine shown as below.

[First time rendering gltf model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXSyI.jpg)

But when I try to change the texture image that has green color using TextureLoader and apply onto my model, it shows up like this as below.

[After changing texture image that has green color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h88sS.jpg)

I thought that the problem might be the GLTFLoader already loaded the original gltf file rendering with .bin file that is not editable once loaded and i am applying external texture image onto it. But it turns out to be it is not the cause of problem because it shows same problem when I apply the same texture image when the model is loaded very first time, it shows the same messed up model with same color.

So basically, I came with this far conclusion. After I succesfully loaded my model as gltf format, updating texture manually is not working correctly. Below is my source code so far. I am sharing the exported gltf model files below.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mZrQHVJHmFv0Q_I1aInqmgA4-WtZDwID

```js
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<%@ page session="false" %>

<!doctype html>

<head>
 <script src="<c:url value="/resources/three.js" />"></script>
 <script src="<c:url value="/resources/three.min.js" />"></script>
 <script src="<c:url value="/resources/OrbitControls.js" />"></script>
 <script src="<c:url value="/resources/GLTFLoader.js" />"></script>
 
 <style type="text/css">

     #canvas {
     width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background: white;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="canvas"></div>

<select id="colorOption" onchange="setAnotherTexture()">
  <option value="blue">blue</option>
  <option value="red">red</option>
  <option value="green">green</option>
  <option value="black">black</option>
</select>

<script type='text/javascript'>
// Set up the scene, camera, and renderer as global variables.
var scene, camera, renderer, modelObj;

init();
animate();

// Sets up the scene.
function init() {

 // Create the [SCENE] and set the scene size.
 scene = new THREE.Scene();
 scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );
 //Create a [RENDERER] and add it to the DOM.
 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
 //renderer.gammaFactor = 2.2;
 
 var container = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var WIDTH = container.offsetWidth;
    var HEIGHT = container.offsetHeight;
    
 renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
 container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
 
 
 // Create a [CAMERA], zoom it out from the model a bit, and add it to the scene.
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 0.1, 20000);
    camera.position.set(0,6,0);
    scene.add(camera);
    
    
    // Update the Viewport on Resize
 // Create an event listener that resizes the renderer with the browser window.
 window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  var WIDTH = container.offsetWidth,
      HEIGHT = container.offsetHeight;
  
  renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  camera.aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    });
 
    
 // Add Lighting
 // Set the background color of the scene.
    renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);
    renderer.gammaOutput = true;
    
    // Create a light, set its position, and add it to the scene.
    var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xbbbbff, 0x444422 );
 //light.position.set( 0, 1, 0 );
 scene.add( light );
 
    
  // Instantiate a loader
    var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader().setPath( 'resources/models/gltf/Hermes_Berkin/' );
 loader.setResourcePath( 'resources/models/gltf/Hermes_Berkin/' );
  
    loader.load( 'hermes.gltf', function ( gltf ) {
  
     modelObj = gltf.scene;
     
     scene.add( modelObj );
     
  console.log(modelObj);
  
    }, undefined, function ( error ) {

     console.error( error );

    } );
    
    
  
    // Add Controls
  // Add OrbitControls so that we can pan around with the mouse.
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    //container.addEventListener("touchstart", handlerFunction, false);

}

//Renders the scene and updates the render as needed.
function animate() {

 // Read more about requestAnimationFrame at http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/
 requestAnimationFrame(animate);
 
 // Render the scene.
 renderer.render(scene, camera);
 controls.update();

}

function setAnotherTexture() {
 var textureColor = document.getElementById("colorOption").value;
 var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
 
 var newTexture = textureLoader.load( "resources/models/gltf/Hermes_Berkin/hermes_birkin_" + textureColor + "_d.jpg");
 
 newTexture.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
 newTexture.flipY = false;

  modelObj.traverse( function ( child ) {
  
  if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
      //create a global var to reference later when changing textures
      //apply texture

      child.material.map = newTexture;
      child.material.needsUpdate = true;
      child.material.map.needsUpdate = true;

  }
 });
 console.log(modelObj);

}
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: /cc https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/15520

Answer (score 1):

This model uses a "repeat" wrapping on the texture, which you'll need to add to the new textures when you add them:

```
newTexture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
newTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
```

I think you have everything else right here, but there are some other common settings described in the *Textures* section of the [GLTFLoader docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/GLTFLoader).